# Show super.view - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I've created ViewControllers ABC and XYZ. XYZ inherits from ABC.
In the AppDelegate, I add XYZ.view as subView.

Now at the click of a button in XYZ I want to display ABC.view on a small portion of screen. I've tried some combinations of the following but nothing works.

1. [self.view bringSubviewToFront:super.view];
2. [appDelegate.window bringSubviewToFront:super.view];
3. [self.view addSubview:super.view];
4. [appDelegate.window insertSubview:self.view atIndex:0];
5. [appDelegate.window insertSubview:super.view aboveSubview:self.view];
6. [super.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super is a keyword that Is used only to invoke the superclass's implementation of a particular method. It does not refer to an actual instance of a class. If you want to create and display a viewcontroller, you have to alloc and init an instance of it, then present it just as you have done with XYZ.

Comment: Going with your suggestion of adding ABC as a subView of XYZ, then what will be the best approach to pass data from ABC to XYZ.
I know of several ways but don't know which is a good one!

Comment: That is a separate question really, but just use properties. If you are trying anything complicated, post a new question (once you've done some research :) )